# Adding image before the "contains" using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Need help on this code below. I don't want to replace the text on which I called in my "a:contains". The problem is where do I need to put the **::before** on the script below.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/onw7aqem/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a:contains(This is the text)").css("content", "url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U')");
});
```

```html
<a href="#">This is the text</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you use id as the selector? Could you describe your requirement with more details?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `::before` is not a jquery function, but a psudeo element creation call in CSS. Did you mean `.before()` or `.after()`? I also updated your code to a Snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("<div>").css("content", "url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U')").appendTo($("a:contains(This is the text)"));
});
```

```html
<a href="#">This is the text</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This creates a `<div>` element and appends it to the `<a>` element.